# Java : Not Able to cast jsonobject to Json array

Tags: java, arrays, json, httpresponse

I was able to pull data from an api using my get request method

```
 {"vulnerabilities":[{"id":5027994,"status":"open","closed_at":null,"created_at":"2019-06-07T06:10:15Z","due_date":null,"notes":null,"port":[],"priority":null,"identifiers":["adobe-reader-apsb09-15-cve-2009-2990"],"last_seen_time":"2019-07-24T05:00:00.000Z","fix_id":4953,"scanner_vulnerabilities":[{"port":null,"external_unique_id":"adobe-reader-apsb09-15-cve-2009-2990","open":true}],"asset_id":119920,"connectors":[{"name":"Nexpose Enterprise","id":7,"connector_definition_name":"Nexpose Enterprise","vendor":"R7"}],"service_ticket":null,"urls":{"asset":"dummy.com"},"patch":true,"patch_published_at":"2009-10-08T22:40:52.000Z","cve_id":"CVE-2009-2990","cve_description":"Array index error in Adobe Reader and Acrobat 9.x before 9.2, 8.x before 8.1.7, and possibly 7.x through 7.1.4 might allow attackers to execute arbitrary code via unspecified vectors.","cve_published_at":"2009-10-19T22:30:00.000Z","description":null,"solution":null,"wasc_id":null,"severity":9,"threat":9,"popular_target":false,"active_internet_breach":true,"easily_exploitable":true,"malware_exploitable":true,"predicted_exploitable":false,"custom_fields":[],"first_found_on":"2019-06-05T05:22:23Z","top_priority":true,"risk_meter_score":100,"closed":false}
```

but in my request method I have received an error in parsing this data , which is that I can not cast an jsonobject to jsonarray.

here is the get request method:

```
public static void GetRequest() {

        BufferedReader reader;
        String access_token = "blahblahblah";       

        String line;
        StringBuffer responseContentReader = new StringBuffer();

        try {

            URL url = new URL("https://api.security.com/vulnerabilities/");
            connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            connection.setRequestProperty("X-Risk-Token ", access_token);


            connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

//here we should be able to "request" our setup
//Here will be the method I will use 
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");

//after 5 sec if the connection is not successful time it out
            connection.setConnectTimeout(5000);
            connection.setReadTimeout(5000);

            int status = connection.getResponseCode();
//System.out.println(status); //here the connect was established  output was 200 (OK)

//here we are dealing with the connection isnt succesful

            if (status > 299) {
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getErrorStream()));
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    responseContentReader.append(" ");
                    responseContentReader.append(line);
                    responseContentReader.append("\n");
                }
                reader.close();
//returns what is successful    
            } else {
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    responseContentReader.append(" ");
                    responseContentReader.append(line);
                    responseContentReader.append("\n");
                }
                reader.close();
            }
            JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
            Object object = parser.parse(responseContentReader.toString());
        JsonArray array = (JsonArray) object;  // here  is where the exception occurs
        for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
            JsonArray jsonArray = (JsonArray) array.get(i);
            JsonObject jsonobj = (JsonObject) jsonArray.get(i);// cannot cast jsonobject to jsonarray
        }
        //JsonObject jsonObject = (JsonObject) object;
            System.out.println( responseContentReader.toString());



        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
// TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            connection.disconnect();
        }

    }
```

here is where the error occurs specifically, I honestly dont know how to go forward with this:

```
JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
            Object object = parser.parse(responseContentReader.toString());
        JsonArray array = (JsonArray) object;  // here  is where the exception occurs
        for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
            JsonArray jsonArray = (JsonArray) array.get(i);
            JsonObject jsonobj = (JsonObject) jsonArray.get(i);// cannot cast jsonobject to jsonarray
        }
        //JsonObject jsonObject = (JsonObject) object;
            System.out.println( responseContentReader.toString());
```

the error message is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.JsonObject cannot be cast to com.google.gson.JsonArray
```

Comment: The data you get back isn't an array. It's a json object that contains an array.

Answer (score 1):

you forgot to close your json with brackets and braces like this:

```
{"vulnerabilities":[{"id":5027994,"status":"open","closed_at":null,"created_at":"2019-06-07T06:10:15Z","due_date":null,"notes":null,"port":[],"priority":null,"identifiers":["adobe-reader-apsb09-15-cve-2009-2990"],"last_seen_time":"2019-07-24T05:00:00.000Z","fix_id":4953,"scanner_vulnerabilities":[{"port":null,"external_unique_id":"adobe-reader-apsb09-15-cve-2009-2990","open":true}],"asset_id":119920,"connectors":[{"name":"Nexpose Enterprise","id":7,"connector_definition_name":"Nexpose Enterprise","vendor":"R7"}],"service_ticket":null,"urls":{"asset":"dummy.com"},"patch":true,"patch_published_at":"2009-10-08T22:40:52.000Z","cve_id":"CVE-2009-2990","cve_description":"Array index error in Adobe Reader and Acrobat 9.x before 9.2, 8.x before 8.1.7, and possibly 7.x through 7.1.4 might allow attackers to execute arbitrary code via unspecified vectors.","cve_published_at":"2009-10-19T22:30:00.000Z","description":null,"solution":null,"wasc_id":null,"severity":9,"threat":9,"popular_target":false,"active_internet_breach":true,"easily_exploitable":true,"malware_exploitable":true,"predicted_exploitable":false,"custom_fields":[],"first_found_on":"2019-06-05T05:22:23Z","top_priority":true,"risk_meter_score":100,"closed":false}]}
```

try this json and it should work!

I highly recommend you use this website for formmating your jsons
https://jsonformatter.org/

Comment: I still reciceved a error  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.JsonObject cannot be cast to com.google.api.services.bigquery.model.JsonObject

Answer (score 0):

Instead of casting, retrieve the array from the object or json response like below:

```
JsonObject object = ...
JsonArray array =  object.getJSONArray("vulnerabilities");
```

Answer (score 0):

The response returned by the `GET` API is not a `JsonArray` but a `JsonObject`.

You can correct the following line -- `JsonArray array = (JsonArray) object;` to --

`JsonObject jsonObject = (JsonObject) object;`

Further, you could read the `"vulnerabilities"` within by --

`JsonArray vulnerabilitiesArray = jsonObject.getJsonArray("vulnerabilities");`

Comment: I still get an error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.JsonObject cannot be cast to com.google.api.services.bigquery.model.JsonObject

Comment: Can you post the entire stack trace? Seems like you're using different types of `JsonObject`. Make sure you are using `com.google.gson.JsonObject`